# Error when trying to use PIL image in Pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pyglet

I have a function which is suposed to generate a random star background using pillow which is then suposed to be used in pyglet:

```
from pyglet.image.codecs.png import PILImageDecoder
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import pyglet
import random

def generate_stars(map_size):
    img = Image.new('RGB', map_size, color='black')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    for _ in range(3):
        for x in range(0, map_size[0] + 1, 3):
            for b in range(400, map_size[1] + 1, 400):
                y = random.randint(b - 400, b)
                draw.rectangle((x,y,x,y),fill='white')
    return pyglet.image.load(img, decoder=PILImageDecoder())

window = pyglet.window.Window(1280,800)
stars = generate_stars((1280,800))
```

However executing this gets me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonaskosinski/Desktop/Python/Game/main_loop.py", line 18, in <module>
    stars = generate_stars((1280,800))
  File "/Users/jonaskosinski/Desktop/Python/Game/main_loop.py", line 15, in generate_stars
    return pyglet.image.load(img, decoder=PILImageDecoder())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 180, in load
    file = open(filename, 'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Image
```

Comment: Looking at the [PIL documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.tobitmap), maybe you need `tobitmap`: `pyglet.image.load(img.tobitmap(), decoder=PILImageDecoder())`

Comment: Although looking at the [PILImageDecoder code](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/src/8d021bd74e3c6e098642c938fba1a01a02b43574/pyglet/image/codecs/pil.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#pil.py-60) it seems it constructs the Image object from a filename. You might want to create your own Decoder based on this where you can pass the Image yourself. If your objective is to create the image in code, why not use [pyglet.image.create](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/image/index.html#pyglet.image.create)?

Comment: @solarc That solved that error but gives me ValueError: not a bitmap

Comment: Yes, see my second comment. The PILImageDecoder also expects the first argument of `pyglet.image.load` to be a filename. If you still want to create the `Image` object yourself you'll have to create your own Decoder that skips loading from the filename and instead creates the `Image` itself.